# Login on mobile application with Phonegap-AJAX

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, authentication

I am making a mobile application on android and I use phonegap, mobile jquery ajax codeigniter and mysql. I have a problem on my login process. My AJAX request failed all the time. I use the same thing on my register process and it works. Its strange.. This is my code on login.html on phonegap:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Login</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

$("input[type=text]").val('');

document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);


function init() {

$('a[id^="submitButton"]').on('click',function(){
$("#submitButton",this).attr("disabled","disabled");
//$("#loginForm").on("submit",function() {


  u = $("#username").val();
  p = $("#password").val();


 if(u!='' && p!='') {



                 $.ajax({

                     url:'http://****.dyndns-home.com/health/index.php/health_login?username='+u+'&password='+p,

                     dataType:'json',
                     success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                        {
                        $.mobile.changePage("menu1.html");

                         if(data.status==1) {
                         localStorage.setItem("username", u);
                         localStorage.setItem("password", p);

                         $.mobile.changePage("menu1.html");
                         $("input[type=text]").val('');


                         }
                          if(data.status==0){
                          alert("Wrong username or password!");
                          $("input[type=text]").val('');
                          }


                         },

                         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        alert('AJAX request failed');
                        }

                         });
}
else{
alert("You must enter a username and password");
}
 return false;




});
}
});
    </script>

</head> 



<body> 
<div data-role="page"> 

    <div data-role="header" >

    <h2>Login</h2></div> 
    <div data-role="content">
    <form id="loginForm">
    Username: <input type="text" id="username" value=""  name="username"/>
    Password:<input type="text" id="password" value=""   name="password"/>
    <a href="forget.html" > Ξέχασες τον κωδικό ή το όνομα χρήστη;</a><br>
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-transition="turn" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" >Back</a>
    <a href="" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="forward">Είσοδος</a>


    </form>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h2></h2></div> 

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Also, when I run my login.html as a web application on chrome and mozzila I got no problem , ajax request success! I run this application on eclipse with api level 15(android 4.0.3).

Tell me if u need my register.html code.

What do u think? 
I'm looking to fix this problem 2 days now and I can't do anything.

Thank you!

Comment: You didn't say how it wasn't working. Is the click event not firing? Is the Ajax call not going out?

Comment: The problem is on ajax request. Ajax call fail, it shows the message on error. As i said before i use the same ajax request with different url and data in my register.html page and its works fine! Also when i run my login.html on my web (chrome, mozzila) it works. So my php-mysql is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Open the emulator's browser and type an Internet address in order to verify that the emulator is able to connect to the Internet. Otherwise the JS and CSS in your page won't load.

In case the emulator is able to connect in the Internet you can try the below code. I have performed some improvements in your code. For example the jQuery framework was loaded multiple times in the same page. The below code has been tested in Android.

Furthermore note that the localStorage you are using to save the credentials, stores data without expiration date. You should consider using the sessionStorage instead of the local storage. The sessionStorage stores data for one session.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Login</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=utf-8>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            /**
             * Clears all the inputs in the page.
             */
            function clearPageInputs() {
                $("input[type=text]").val('');
            }


            /**
             * Trim function
             */
            String.prototype.trim = function() {
                a = this.replace(/^\s+/, '');
                return a.replace(/\s+$/, '');
            };

            /**
             * Submits the login form
             */
            function sumbitLoginForm(user, pass) {
                if (user.trim() == '' || pass.trim() == '')
                {   
                    // fill username and password in Greek language
                    alert("\u03a3\u03c5\u03bc\u03c0\u03bb\u03ae\u03c1\u03c9\u03c3\u03b5 \u03c4\u03bf Username \u03ba\u03b1\u03b9 \u03c4\u03bf Password!");
                }
                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'http://.../.../...',
                        data: { username: user, password: pass },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data) {
                            if(data && data.status == 1) {
                                // save in local storage
                                localStorage.setItem("username", user);
                                localStorage.setItem("password", pass);
                                // perform page transition 
                                $.mobile.changePage("menu1.html");
                            }
                            else {
                                clearPageInputs()
                                // wrong username / password in Greek language
                                alert("\u0388\u03c7\u03b5\u03b9\u03c2 \u03ba\u03ac\u03bd\u03b5\u03b9 \u03ba\u03ac\u03c0\u03bf\u03b9\u03bf \u03bb\u03ac\u03b8\u03bf\u03c2 \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf Username \u03ae/\u03ba\u03b1\u03b9 \u03c3\u03c4\u03bf Password.");
                            }   
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + "\n" +
                                   "Message: " + xhr.statusText + "\n" +
                                   "Response: " + xhr.responseText + "\n" + thrownError);
                        }
                    });
                }

                return false;
            }

            $(document).ready( function() {
                clearPageInputs();

                $("#submitButton").click(function(){
                    sumbitLoginForm($("#username").val(), $("#password").val());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div data-role="page"> 
            <div data-role="header" >
            <h2>Login</h2></div> 
            <div data-role="content">
                <form id="loginForm">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" value=""  name="username"/>
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="password" value=""   name="password"/>
                    <a href="forget.html">Ξέχασες τον κωδικό ή το όνομα χρήστη;</a><br>
                    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-transition="turn" data-inline="true" data-icon="back" >Back</a>
                    <a href="#" id="submitButton" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="forward">Είσοδος</a>
                </form>
            </div> 
            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h2></h2></div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all i would like to thank u a lot for your reply. I fixed my problem with my code because i changed the datatype from json to text. I tried your code but when i have json on datatype my request fail. i cant understand why. On my server side i got json encode it works sucessfully. Do u have any idea why there is problem with json?

Comment: My error msg is : Error: 200
Message: OK
Response: {"data":[{"\u038c\u03bd\u03bf\u03bc\u03b1..............":"sd","\u0395\status":1,"message":"Success!"}
SyntaxError: invalid label

Comment: The "\u0395\status" is invalid label. You will have to change the label name. You can check the validity on the http://jsonlint.com/ validator. This is a valid response: {"data": [ { "\u038c\u03bd\u03bf\u03bc\u03b1..............": "sd", "status": 1, "message": "Success!" } ] }. In conclusion the current JSON response is invalid, that's the cause of the issue.

Comment: More specifically the \u0395\status is invalid because of the last slash \. If you change it in \u0395\\status it is valid and it corresponds to the native text E\status where E is a Greek letter.